# How to return Deferred with the instant result?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I have a conditional statement which should return `Deferred` result in both cases, but I don't know how to manually create `Deferred` object with predefined result. Here's code snapshot:

```
val deferredResult = if (condition) {
   callSuspendFunction(params)
} else {
  deferred???
}
```

`callSuspendFunction` returns the result of `async` operation. Although I can write something like `coroutineScope { async { result } }` instead of `deferred???`, but it looks really not what it should be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a `CompletableDeferred`, see https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-completable-deferred/

```
val value = if(true) {
    callSuspendFunction(params)
} else {
    CompletableDeferred(10)
}
```

Answer (score -4):

you can drictlly use like below.
In first condition it will return int and in second case it will return boolean

```
   val deferredResult = if (condition) {
        3
    } else {
      true
    }
```